# Partition a number $n$ in exactly sum of $k$ distinct numbers such that product of the numbers should be maximum.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, integer-partitions

The question is to partition a given number $n$ in exactly sum of $k$ distinct positive numbers such that the product of $k$ distinct number become maximum. $k$ will be given optimally so that it will be possible to partition.

For example:

1-$n$=5 and $k$ =2 partitions are {1,5} and {2,3} so answer will be max(1*5,2*3) i.e equal to 6.

2-$n$=6 and $k$=2 partitions will be {5,1} and {4,2} answer will be 8.

3-$n$=7 and $k$=3 partition will be {1,3,4} and {1,4,2} answer will be max(1*3*4,1*4*2)
i.e equal to 12.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will follow in future.

Comment: Basically you need to make them as close to $n/k$ as possible

Comment: Yes, but how can I chose the number after then.Rest of the k-1 distinct number.

Comment: Note that $1+3+4=8$

Comment: Yes but how you divided it. for n=8 and k=3. ceil(8/3)=4 ,n=8-4and k=2 then ceil(4/2)=2. remaining n=2 and k=1. I want the recurrence formula for it.If possible

Comment: It will be minimum when variance of k numbers will be minimum.

Comment: What is the intention of the sentence "$k$ will be given optimally so that it will be possible to partition"? Can $k$ be any number, or will it be determined by some higher wisdom unknown to us? This then would lead to a different problem.

Comment: n>=kC2.this is the constraint for optimal selection of k